# Google Sheets- Expanding Serials from Varying Ranges based on Quantity

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Have thousands of serial #'s that have a start and end range column; but need #'s to be fully written out in separate cells.  Range is defined by the Quantity of items, which varies.  Not sure if it is easier to have the expanded range in cells to the right, a new tab or in separate columns but open to either.  Attached a test doc to replicate issue.

[Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1afKtaWzBSjmG7DlV6rwsvo-jXuzJMhT3als6cmpsOSU/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You have disabled edit and make-copy in the sample spreadsheet, which makes answering more difficult. You may want to replace `125009` with `1250009` in cell `C3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `sequence()` function like this:

`=sequence(1, D2 - C2 + 1, C2)`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(C2:C="",,IF(SPLIT(REPT("×¤", D2:D-C2:C+1), "×")="",,C2:C-1+COLUMN(1:1))))
```

[image]